# MySQL/Python - MySQLdb does not recognise table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I get the following error:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test.imageupload' doesn't exist")

The database and table are there. I have dropped and created them again. I have also tried restarting the server. Nothing seems to work.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root",         # your username
                         passwd=" ",          # your password
                         db="test")           # name of the data base
cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("""INSERT INTO imageupload (uid, image_path,image_name) values (%s,%s,%s)""", (122, "kkk", "lll"))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Run `USE test; SHOW TABLES;` What is the output?

Comment: Empty set. But I have created the database and table in phpmyadmin. What's the problem?

Comment: When I run SHOW ALL DATABASES; I can see all the databases I have created but I can't see their tables.

Comment: Then for whatever reason you did not create any tables. You possibly did not select a database when creating tables or maybe they were temporary ones. Run `USE test; CREATE TABLE ...` and try again in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested if you are successfully connecting to the **db**?
if yes, try creating the table via `cur.execute()`

Comment: Table does get created. I can see it on my mysql but not on my phpmyadmin.